# Writing a Yaml file

Tags: php, yaml

I would like to write a yml file and tried it with this code:

```
try {
    $array = array('firstname' => 'Ray', 'lastname' => 'Zah');
    yaml_emit_file('../../config.yml', $array);
    echo "done!\n";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

But I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function yaml_emit_file()

I have tested it local on MAMP and also on the live server. In php.ini I have added `extension=yaml.so` but nothing works.

How can I call this function?

Comment: you added the ini stuff, but it sounds like you didn't actually install it

Answer (score 1):

This function is part of yaml PECL extension which is not included in PHP. You must install this extension on your own, look at: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/yaml.installation.php for details. This extension also require LibYAML C Library to be present on your system.

Alternatively you can use pure PHP YAML library. Few open-source solution are available. I suggest this one: https://github.com/symfony/yaml documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html